# Query to check the degree of parallelism on a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How does one query an Oracle 10g database to determine the degree of parallelism for a table?  My searches have proved fruitless.  I would anticipate it is something like this:

```
select degree   
from table_metadata
```

where `table_metadata` is metadata about my table.

Since parallelism seems to be unknown consider the following statement:

```
create table  foo  
...  
parallel (8);
```

Here `parallel (8)` sets the degree of parallelism to 8

Comment: @Hogan when you create a table you can do this:  `create table foo parallel (8)`.  the phrase `parallel (8)` is the degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT degree
  FROM user_tables
 WHERE table_name = <<some table name>>
```

will work assuming that you own the table.  Otherwise, depending on your privileges, either use `ALL_TABLES` or `DBA_TABLES` rather than `USER_TABLES` and add a predicate on the `OWNER` column.

Comment: Default degree is 1. If you specify the DOP during table creation it will help set to that degree of parallelism.